# Windows 8 Mobile Button Background not responding?

Tags: c#, button, windows-8, windows-mobile

I am trying to change the background color of a button dynamically in a windows 8 mobile application.

The button from Mainpage.xaml:

```
 <Button Name="RedButton" Click="RedButton_Click_1" Width="200" Height="100" Content="Red" Margin="136,171,144,497"/>
```

Code from Mainpage.xaml.cs

```
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
                {

                    RedButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red); 

                });
```

**The code does not modify the background of the red button object at all.** What is causing this communication?

Comment: try this RedButton.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { RedButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red); }));

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you change the colour from the xaml file instead of the class? You can also use the properties window to change attributes.

```
Background="Colour"
Foreground="Colour"
BorderBrush="Colour"
```

Comment: I am trying to do it dynamically, so it changes color from color depending on input

Comment: Try:

`RedButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);`

Comment: I get the error 'Windows.UI.Color' does not contain a definition for 'Red'